# 2D Collision Resolution

Tags: user-interface, geometry, collision

I am currently working on a user interface, in which it is possible, to add objects by clicking on the screen. I don't want any overlapping objects. While it is easy to detect, whether a collision between 2 objects occurred, i am still struggling with resolving these conflicts.

Currently, i am resolving the conflicts locally by moving the intruding object away from the collision. This, however, may lead to new collisions, which are resolved in the same manner. Unfortunately, there is no guarantee, that this process will ever stop.

Are there any standard problems this relates to or algorithms to use? Or any efficient solutions which are not prone to endless recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I thought of it more I think you just move all the objects that lie in the direction of the move that you are already doing. Doing it this way you basically solve the problem of possible endless recursion.

Since you should know the size of your objects to move and the direction of a smart movement this should solve the problem

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution to my problem. I will try to implement it later and give you feedback afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of how you can resolve your problems is by implementing a "grid snap" behavior.

Basically, there are only predefined areas in your frame where the user can add UI elements---the grid cells. When a user drops a UI element on your frame, you should detect where in the grid does it fall mainly (you can choose your own behavior in case it falls equally across two or more grid cells). This way, you need not detect collision between two UI elements at all.

## Edit

Well, I certainly did not anticipate the cases you outlined in your comment. If the sizes of your objects will vary by that much, I admit that "grid snap" may not be applicable to your situation---you might end up with a lot of empty space. I was thinking of something along the lines of Visual Basic when I composed my answer (VB, as far as I remember *does* implement some sort of grid snap behavior).

A minor point though: while you may have your user's best interests at heart by letting them have an exact control of the positioning of UI elements, think of how your users will interface with your program. Positioning things exactly on the screen using a mouse can be punishment and it may just backfire on you. The same, however, cannot be said if you are guaranteed that your users will always use a touchscreen device.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to agree with jenzzaflow. It does not seem to actually solve to problem and as the size of my objects may vary i am not exactly sure, how i would compute the grid size to still maintain a pleasant feel for the user. I wouldn't want the user to notice the grid, as the exact layouting of the objects is of importance and i can relate to the unnerving feeling of wanting to position something at an exact position and being prevented from this by a grid.

Comment: I have updated my answer with regards to the details you added. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

"grid snap" is avoiding the problem but not a solution to the problem.

As Sarah pointed out you can solve this by moving your objects a random distance into one direction and then check again if there is a collision, then move the colliding object. However, this can lead to exponential growth of the problem.

Instead you can try to implement a light physics engine where your objects "bounce" against each other and using friction come to a halt after some time. Try to google for continuous collision avoidance.